# Copying folders to different destination

Tags: python

I'm looking to transfer a whole bunch of folders to a different destination, inside these folders there are a bunch of different folders, now I have a made a list of only the relevant folders that should be coped

```
folders_listed = ['Green_leaf', 'red_bark', 'Gene_pea', 'Tres_ig']
```

The idea is if there is match in `final_source` and `folders_listed` copy the files,

But this isn't exactly working as I thought.

```
import shutil
import os
source = os.listdir("/media/task_one/ce162bb5-5654-4c36-9db2-55c7728ddb5a/LiverCT/username/PhaseWise/")
destination = "/media/task_one/da5df9e4-cdc6-4d55-91e8-b2383e89165f/Ryan/"
for files in source:
    final_source = os.listdir('/media/task_one/ce162bb5-5654-4c36-9db2-55c7728ddb5a/LiverCT/username/PhaseWise/'+files+'/')
    for final_files in final_source:
        if final_files in folders_listed:
            os.mkdir('/media/task_one/da5df9e4-cdc6-4d55-91e8-b2383e89165f/Ryan/'+files)
            shutil.copy(final_files,'/media/task_one/da5df9e4-cdc6-4d55-91e8-b2383e89165f/Ryan/'+files)



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1181-d61f9349b171> in <module>()
      8         if final_files in folders_listed:
      9             os.mkdir('/media/task_one/da5df9e4-cdc6-4d55-91e8-b2383e89165f/Ryan/'+files)
---> 10             shutil.copy(final_files,'/media/task_one/da5df9e4-cdc6-4d55-91e8-b2383e89165f/Ryan/'+files)

/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py in copy(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    233     if os.path.isdir(dst):
    234         dst = os.path.join(dst, os.path.basename(src))
--> 235     copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
    236     copymode(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
    237     return dst

/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py in copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    112         os.symlink(os.readlink(src), dst)
    113     else:
--> 114         with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
    115             with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
    116                 copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Green_leaf'
```

Comment: show what you expect and what you got.

Comment: have made the edits

Comment: You want to look at `shutil.copytree` and the ignore patterns.

Comment: @sytech Thanks, can you tell me what do you mean by ignore patterns?

Comment: IIRC, you can pass a function to `copytree`'s `ignore` parameter. As `copytree` traverses the directory, it gives the function the directory and files. The function should return the things that should be ignored. So, you should be able to make a function that will ignore everything when the directory is not in your list.

Comment: the  ignore parameter is helpful ,but i have an issue is that i have close to 1000 patterns(i mean folder names to ignore),but it isnt accepting anything more than 255,what do i do?